Check if templated class with variadic NTTP derives from similarly templated base?
I've been trying to figure out how write a concept that checks whether one class that takes a parameter pack of non-type template parameters derives from another.  I've tried many iterations but cant for the life of me figure out how it would be done and at this point I'm questioning if it's even possible.
struct A {
  size_t x, y;
};

template <A... as>
class Base {
public:
    Base() = delete;
};

template <A... as>
class Sub : Base<as...> {};

using foo = Sub<{1, 2}, {3, 4}>;

// Concept to check if a type derives from Base
template <typename T>
concept DerivesFromBase;

static_assert(DerivesFromBase<foo>, "foo must derive from Base");

Anyone have any clever ideas or can confirm whether it's possible?

What is "derives from Base" supposed to mean? Whether it derives from any specialization of Base or a specific one (e.g. the one with equivalent template argument list)?

From a specialization with the same template argument list

using foo = Sub<{1, 2}, {3, 4}>; already fails to compile btw. because x and y are private in A

template<typename>
struct DerivesFromBaseImpl;

template<template<A...> class Tmpl, A... as>
struct DerivesFromBaseImpl<Tmpl<as...>> : std::is_base_of<Base<as...>, Tmpl<as...>> {};

typename<typename T>
concept DerivesFromBase = DerivesFromBaseImpl<T>::value;

Please consider the notes about is_base_of at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of. It might not check exactly what you need. (consider e.g. what if T is Base<...>, what about ambiguous, indirect, private inheritance, etc.?)

You should consider tagging your classes, either with an empty base class:
struct tag_Base {};

template <typename... As> 
    struct Base : tag_Base {/*...*/};

or with constexpr members:
template <typename... As>
struct Base {
    constexpr static bool is_a_base = true;
};

Then your concepts can be written simply as:
template <typename T>
concept DerivesFromBase = std::derived_from< T, tag_Base >;

or
template <typename T>
concept DerivesFromBase = requires{ {T::is_a_base}; };

